# Why I get Internal Server Error after publishing Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, internal-server-error

I've made an API in Azure Functions that uses an Azure Sql database.
I have this route:

```
    [FunctionName("GetAllClassesForTeacher")]
    public IActionResult GetAllClassesForTeacher(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
     ILogger log)
    {
        var headers = req.Headers;
        if (headers.TryGetValues("TeacherId", out var Teacher))
        {
            int TeacherId = Convert.ToInt32(Teacher.First());

            var result = _classDistributionServices.GetAllClassesForTeacher(TeacherId);

            if (result != null)
            {
                return new OkObjectResult(result);
            }
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }
        return new NotFoundResult();
    }
```

When tested localy, it works everytime. But after publishing it on Azure Portal, I get back from postman:

```
{
"statusCode": 500,
"message": "Internal server error",
"activityId": "f98c4112-0c31-4841-99a5-c79dffa41d86"
```

What I've tried/did until now:

- to take the IP from Azure Function and register it in Firewalls and
  virtual networks from Azure Sql Server.
- I've made sure that the ConnectionString from local.settings.json it 
  is uploaded on portal.
- I've declared this route in API Management.

But still the error persists.
I have a feeling that is still because of database firewall even if I've registered the right IP?

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few way for you to figure out what is the problem:

1-Enable Application Insights and use the Live Metrics to capture the error

2-Use Kudu and check for more details about the error (e.g. https://myfunctionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions)

3-You can also wrap your code with a try/catch and throw details of the exception in the response output.

Comment: After setting up Application Insights, the error messaged logged there from the specific function was that "could not access the server from ip...". So I went again to give access to that IP, but it was already there. I discovered from a friend that I could test my function from directly from Azure (not from API Management) and from there everything worked normal. So I've compared the URLs from API Management and from function itself and was different. I don't know why the Function App would throw me a 500 internal in case the URL in wrong, but at least I figured it out. Thank you too.